# C# Unable to create class level object

Tags: c#

I have a class, in which I want to create an instance of an XDocument. In the constructor I need to call the "Load" method, but for some reason it is not available to call.

For example:

```
class MyClass
{
    private XDocument xmlResponse;

    public MyClass(string url)
    {
        xmlResponse.Load(url);
    }
}
```

I get the error "cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead"

So I tried "MyClass.xmlResponse.Load(url)" but I'm getting the same error.

What is the proper way of calling the method?

Answer (score 6):

The [`XDocument.Load`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb343181%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method is static, so you have to call it statically. Try this:

```
public MyClass(string url)
{
    xmlResponse = XDocument.Load(url);
}
```

**Further Reading**

- [Static Classes and Static Class Members (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

You want:

```
public MyClass(string url)
{
    xmlResponse = XDocument.Load(url);
}
```

`Load` method is a static method on `XDocument` class, so you can't call it via an instance of `XDocument`.

Answer (score -1):

```
private XDocument xmlResponse;
xmlResponse = new XDocument();
```

try this. object has to be created before accessing xmlResponse